# isCustomerLogged() vs checking checkout customer ID

Tags: customer, session

Is there a difference between using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerId();
```

versus:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isCustomerLogged()
```

for the purpose of checking if a customer is logged in or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') is for creating checkout session object whereas `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` is creating customer session object.
If you need to find check if the customer is logged in or not then second one is much much better. 
And, also `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCustomerId()`; will not provide anything unless there is product in your cart.

Comment: In my case, I don't want my oberserver to be called unless there is something in the cart, but this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call certain block when customer is logged than use below code in your layout file

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <block type="block_type" name="block.name" template="phtml_file_path" />
</customer_logged_in>
```

or for checking if customer is logged in than use below code

```
$this->helper(’customer’)->isLoggedIn();
```